# how to set parent div to get responsive multilevel menu

Tags: 7, routes, nodes, theming

i am newbie to drupal, 
now I am trying to get responsive menu style through this module ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu(codrobs)(http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/), 
but i dont know how to set parent div for following menu

```
Settings for chosen menu style.
Selector(s) to use for this style:
Parent of the <ul>. Example: Given <div id="parent-div"> <ul class="menu"> </ul> </div> you would use #parent-div

<ul class="nice-menu nice-menu-down nice-menu-main-menu" id="nice-menu-1">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <ul>
```

Kindly help me to set parent div to achieve this type of menu style in drupal, share your ideas also

Comment: I don't think that you should use responsive menu with nice menus together (but if you do you might need some extra CSS and jQuery to get them to play together). Rather have two menus, one for the desktop (nice menus) and another for responsive, and then hide them respectively with a media query. Besides that, the markup you provided only shows the ul tag and not its wrapper element. You need to target the wrapper element with your selector. There are other menu solutions that have desktop flyouts and responsive menus in one, such as TBMegamenu.

Comment: By the way, as far as I remember you need to flush your caches each time you add a new menu (if you are using [Responsive Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus))

Comment: @J.Reynolds thanks, currently i have used nice menu for desktops and simple expanding for mobile and other devices. but i will try to get ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu(codrobs) module style on mobile devices